# Dynamically display length as type in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to dynamically display the length as I type, but haveno idea how to go about it. It must update with every letter that is typed or deleted. For example
"Iam" Length=3
"Ia" Length = 2
Of course I can do this statically by clicking a button or pressing enter, but I want this to happen as I type. Please help

Comment: There are [*many questions*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+count+characters+typed) on this already, did you look? Or try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

input event is a bit patchy so use [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) event instead.

Here is the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98nz45u8/2/).

Thanks, @robg, for reminding me in the comment.

---

**Original Answer:**

You can use [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event on an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element. Different from [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event, the DOM input event is fired synchronously when the value of an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element is changed.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var p = document.querySelector('p');
var i = 0;
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  p.innerHTML = input.value.length;
})
```

```html
<input/>
<p>The length of the value</p>
```

<del>Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98nz45u8/)</del>

Comment: Support for the input event is a bit patchy, perhaps keyup might be better. It will work as users type, but may miss some types of update (e.g. pasting with context menu or drag and drop).

Comment: It looks like the jsfiddle you're linking to is still using the input event. Here is a forked one using keyup: https://jsfiddle.net/prxqm4dm/.

Comment: @iplus26 That's the one I'm looking at, it has this code: `var input = document.querySelector('keyup');`. I think you bungled it.

Comment: @voltrevo Oops... I thought I've fixed that... Thank you for pointing it out. I've updated the link.

Comment: Hey I see this working in JSfiddle, but im a little confused what is the <input/> doing

Answer (score 1):

> Solution using Jquery

with this HTML

```
<input/>
<div>

</div>
```

And this Jquery

```
$('input').on('keyup blur change paste',function(){
    $('div').html($(this).val().length);
});
```

This will handle events like keyup, blur, change, paste. Here is the [working JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/fo7cot2m/)

Comment: A rather gratuitous use of jQuery. What you're really suggesting is putting 4 listeners on the element, but why stop there? Whey not include paste, input and keydown as well? BTW, `this).val()` is just a very inefficient way of doing `this.value`.

Comment: @RobG thanks for the inputs, I didn't know that `(this).val()` is inefficient. Can you please share more information on this?